# Writing a static method to call methods from another class to return a new list from an old list

Tags: java, class, methods, static

An Aircraft is defined by the following Java class:

```
public class AirCraft
{
   private String make;
   private int numSeats;

   public AirCraft(String make, int numSeats)
   {
      this.make = make;
      this.numSeats = numSeats;
   }

   public String getMake()
   {
      return make;
   }

   public int getNumSeats()
   {
      return numSeats;
   }
   
   public String toString()
   {
       return make + " -> " + numSeats;
   }
}
```

I have to write a method that takes a list of aircraft as a parameter that will find the names of aircrafts that have between 20 and 100 seats let's say and to return a new list that returns these aircraft and the number of seats they have. It has to be a static method of a Test class and must call medium(). This is what I have attempted thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Test
    {
        // Add a static method called medium to this class.
        public static void medium(AirCraft [] group)
        {   
            List <String> aircrafts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < group.length; i++)
            
                if(group[i].getNumSeats() >= 20 && group[i].getNumSeats() <= 100)
                {
                    aircrafts.add(group[i]);
                }
            for(String str: aircrafts)
            {
                System.out.println(str.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the test code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AC
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      AirCraft [] group = {
               new AirCraft("Douglas", 110),
               new AirCraft("Messerschmitt", 90),
               new AirCraft("Boeing", 300),
               new AirCraft("Lockheed", 90),
               new AirCraft("Airbus", 70),
               new AirCraft("Zeppelin", 1000),
               new AirCraft("Victory", 55),
               new AirCraft("McDonnellD", 63),
               new AirCraft("Tupolev", 63),
            };

      // Convert array to a List
      List<AirCraft> aircraft = Arrays.asList(group);
      
      // Call the student's program
      List<AirCraft> medium = Test.medium(aircraft);

      for(AirCraft ac : medium)
         System.out.println(ac);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the problems.

- public static void medium(AirCraft [] group)

  ```
    change void to List<AirCraft>
  ```
- `List <String> aircrafts = new ArrayList<String>();`

  ```
    change to `List<AirCraft>`
  ```
- and return your `List<AirCraft>` at the end of the method.
- Change other`List<String>` to `List<AirCraft>` where necessary
- The following

```
       for (String str : aircrafts) {
            System.out.println(str.toString());
        }
```

```
should be
```

```
       for (AirCraft ac : aircrafts) {
            System.out.println(ac);
        }
```

- And here

```
        // Convert array to a List
        List<AirCraft> aircraft = Arrays.asList(group);
        
        // Call the student's program
        List<AirCraft> medium = Test.medium(aircraft);
```

Why not just call `medium` with an array?  Anyway, you are calling with a `List` but `medium` expects an array.

Here are the changes which seem to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AirCraft[] group = { new AirCraft("Douglas", 110),
                new AirCraft("Messerschmitt", 90),
                new AirCraft("Boeing", 300),
                new AirCraft("Lockheed", 90),
                new AirCraft("Airbus", 70),
                new AirCraft("Zeppelin", 1000),
                new AirCraft("Victory", 55),
                new AirCraft("McDonnellD", 63),
                new AirCraft("Tupolev", 63), };
        
        // Convert array to a List
        List<AirCraft> aircraft = Arrays.asList(group);
        // Call the student's program
        List<AirCraft> medium = Test.medium(aircraft);
        
        for (AirCraft ac : medium)
            System.out.println(ac);
    }
}

class AirCraft {
    private String make;
    private int numSeats;
    
    public AirCraft(String make, int numSeats) {
        this.make = make;
        this.numSeats = numSeats;
    }
    
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    
    public int getNumSeats() {
        return numSeats;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return make + " -> " + numSeats;
    }
}

class Test {
    // Add a static method called medium to this class.
    public static List<AirCraft> medium(List<AirCraft> planes) {
        List<AirCraft> aircrafts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AirCraft ac : planes) {
            
            if (ac.getNumSeats() >= 20
                    && ac.getNumSeats() <= 100) {
                aircrafts.add(ac);
            }
        }
        for (AirCraft ac : aircrafts) {
            System.out.println(ac);
        }
        return aircrafts;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to return it in AirCraft format this is how it's meant to look -
Messerschmitt -> 90
Lockheed -> 90
Airbus -> 70
Victory -> 55
McDonnellD -> 63
Tupolev -> 63

Comment: Ok. I will modify my answer with suggestions.

Comment: I can't edit the test code but that shouldn't effect it no?

Comment: Because I'm still getting the following error message error: incompatible types: List<AirCraft> cannot be converted to AirCraft[]
        List<AirCraft> medium = Test.medium(group);

Comment: Are you saying you can't change your Test class?

Comment: I can't edit the AC or AirCraft classes sorry, I've updated the Test class

Comment: Ok, keep all your other code but just look at the Test class I posted.

Answer (score 0):

i thing u should remove void and put List   and  add return aircrafts in the medium method